# Xcode crash during signing

Tags: swift, crash, cocoapods, xcode8, quartzcode

When I try to run my app on emulator or real device, during the build, Xcode crash always in this step :

[image: Signin]

The problem was appear when I add custom View for animation ( generated with QuartzCode ). Do you think there is a conflict with one of my pod ( or with Xcode ) ?

List of my pod :

> pod 'Alamofire'
>
> pod 'ReachabilitySwift
>
> pod 'SwiftyJSON'
>
> pod 'SAConfettiView'
>
> pod 'MIBlurPopup'
>
> pod "TextFieldEffects" <= I think this pod is the problem but I removed it and problem is stay here
>   pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
>
> pod 'OneSignal'
>
> pod 'Spring'
>
> pod "SACountingLabel"
>
> pod 'RAMAnimatedTabBarController'
>
> pod 'PullToRefreshSwift'
>
> pod 'AdColony'
>
> pod 'AlertOnboarding'
>
> pod 'Firebase/Core'
>
> pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

Comment: Does Xcode show any error messages?

Comment: @tofucodes , no, no message but I reported this bug to apple enginers and they are working on the problem